# Verification of identity $2\sum_{m,n\geq 1\,;\,m>n}\frac{1}{m^k n^k}=\left(\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^k}\right)^2 -\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^{2k}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, proof-writing

Is this identity true?
$$2\sum_{m,n\geq 1\,;\,m>n}\frac{1}{m^k n^k}=\left(\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^k}\right)^2 -\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^{2k}}$$
If so, how to prove it? Could you provide me a comprehensive answer that offers an insight into my understanding of this identity, please? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the $k=2$ case? or the other even cases, where the right hand is known?

Comment: @andre Ya, it's true for, at least, $k=2$ and $k=3$

Comment: Then you might show us these two proofs as the part of what you've already done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to express the squared sum properly:

Write it using two index :

$$\left(\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^k}\right)^2 = \left(\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^k}\right) \left(\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{1}{m^k}\right) = \sum_{m,n\geq 1\,;\,m,n>=1}\frac{1}{m^k n^k}$$

Now you will distinguish the case: $n = m$, it gives the sum of the $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n^{2k}}$ and the case $n$ different from $m$. Here $m$ and $n$ plays symmetrical roles so you can say that:

$m \neq n\,\iff\, n < m$ or $n > m $:

$$\sum_{m,n\geq 1\,;\,m \neq n}\frac{1}{m^k n^k} = \sum_{m,n\geq 1\,;\,m>n}\frac{1}{m^k n^k} + \sum_{m,n\geq 1\,;\,n>m}\frac{1}{m^k n^k} = 2\sum_{m,n\geq 1\,;\,m>n}\frac{1}{m^k n^k}$$

So you get:

$$\left(\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^k}\right)^2 = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^{2k}} + 2\sum_{m,n\geq 1\,;\,m>n}\frac{1}{m^k n^k}$$

See what I did with the re-arrangement of the sum?

Comment: Ugh, I can't read your answer. Please use LaTeX

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm still new to this site and I'm still learning it. Essentially the idea is to write your squared sum with two index (n and m) and separate the double sum according to n=m and n differs from m

Comment: The case n=m give the sum with the square, and the other takes into account :n<m and n>m, and both conditions are symetrical so you get the factor 2

Comment: Use this http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/146687

Comment: Ok thanks to you, I'll try to learn it as fast as possible. But did you get at least the essence of the proof? It requires a certain familiarity with sum manipulations, it's very usual to do things like that with squared sums

Comment: Please edit first your proof. I'm dizzy when reading it

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to but I'm not gifted for that :)

Comment: OK, +1 for your answer

Comment: Thx, I've added some details to show you all the steps